# Determine if a series defined by cases is convergent and calculate the sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, where $a_n$ is $$3^{-n}$$ if $n$ is even and $$\ln \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{n(n+3)}$$ if $n$ is odd.

I have to say if it is convergent and calculate its sum, but the formulation of the problem puzzles me. How should I proceed?

Comment: Split the series into the even-indexed and odd-indexed terms, look at each separately.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: The series is absolutely convergent, so you can split it:

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}a_n=\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{2n}+\sum_{n\ge 1}a_{2n-1}\;.$$

The first series on the righthand side is easy to deal with, so you’re left with

$$\sum_{n\ge 1}\ln\frac{2n(2n+1)}{(2n-1)(2n+2)}\;;$$

use properties of the logarithm to rewrite this and do some slightly complicated telescoping.

Comment: How do you know that it is absolutely convergent?

Comment: You can use the comparison test; $a_n$ is $O(n^{-2})$, for instance.

Comment: @user62029: One way is to split the partial sums the same way in order to evaluate them. Note that it’s a positive series, so if it converges at all, it convergse absolutely. Thus, you might as well tentatively assume that it converges absolutely in order to work with it, and justify the assumption after the fact.

Comment: Could you clarify why if it is positive then, if it converges, it converges absolutely?

Comment: @user62029: That’s immediate from the definition of absolute convergence: $\sum_na_n$ converges absolutely if and only if $\sum_n|a_n|$ converges, and if the series is positive, then $\sum_n|a_n|$ and $\sum_na_n$ are identical.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: For the sum involving logarithms, use the fact that $\ln 1+x \approx x$ whenever $x$ is close to zero and write

$$
\ln \frac{(n+2)(n+1)}{n(n+3)}=\ln \frac{n^2+3n+2}{n^2+3n}= \ln \Bigg( \frac{n^2+3n}{n^2+3n}+\frac{2}{n^2+3n}\Bigg)= \ln \Bigg(1+\frac{2}{n^2+3n}\Bigg).
$$